# NVCC attempting to link unnecessary objects

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, linker, nvcc

I have a project that I'm working on making run with CUDA.  For various reasons, it needs to compile an executable either with or without GTK support, *without* recompiling all of the associated files.  Under C, I accomplished this by compiling a base version of the objects to `*.o` and a GTK version of the objects to `*.gtk.o`.  Thus, I can link to that library and if it needs to use GTK it will pull in those functions (and their requirements); if it doesn't it won't touch those objects.

Converting to `nvcc` has caused some issues: it works in either always or never GTK mode; but if I compile the libraries with the additional GTK objects, it refuses to ignore them and link a GTKless executable. (It fails with errors about being unable to find the cairo functions I call.)

I'm guessing that `nvcc` is linking to (at least one of) its helper functions embedded in the object, which is causing the linker to resolve the entire object.

Running `ar d <lib> <objects.gtk.o>` to manually strip them from the library will "fix" the problem, so there isn't a real dependency there.

I'm compiling/linking with

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --compiler-options -Wall --compiler-options -pipe 
        -rdc=true -O0 -g -G -I inc -I inc/ext -arch compute_20 -o program 
        program.cu obs/external.o libs/base.a libs/extra.a libs/core.a -lm
```

How can I get nvcc to ignore the unneeded objects?

Comment: I am confused by the question. Your stated goal is to compile an application either with, or without, GTK support. You also say, "it works in either always or never GTK mode", which indicates to me that you already achieved your goal. So I am not sure what you are asking. In practical terms, one convenient approach could be to collect all objects files referencing GTK into mylib_GTK.a, all object files that do not reference GTK into mylib.a, and then link your app against the appropriate of the two libraries.

Comment: As in, if I compile libraries with GTK, then use them to compile in GTK mode, it works.  Simiarly, it works if both are compiled without.  However, if the library is compiled with GTK, I cannot compile my application without it.  Yes, making two separate would technically work, but is strongly unpreferred.  I have demonstrated that this works when done with gcc (no CUDA), because unused code isn't included in the final executable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a linker optimization that aggressively removes unused object modules when linking against a static library? Other than bloating executable file size, is there a problem with including unused object code in the executable (I can't think of any as the code isn't used by the app). Considering filing an enhancement request with NVIDIA to make nvcc's behavior more similar to gcc.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get nvcc to ignore the unneeded objects?

Before you can achieve that, you need to understand which symbol is causing the `*.gtk.o` objects to be pulled in from the library when they shouldn't be.

The way to do that is to run link with `-Wl,--print-map`, and look for linker messages such as:

```
Archive member included because of file (symbol)
libfoo.a(foo.o)               main.o (foo)
```

Above, `main.o` referenced `foo`, which is defined in `libfoo.a(foo.o)`, which caused `foo.o` to be pulled in into the main binary.

Once you know *which symbols* cause `xxxx.gtk.o` to be pulled into the link, searching the web and/or NVidia documentation may reveal a way to get rid of them.